# RestClient is not waiting for api response or sometimes it is giving the response and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: c#, fastapi, restsharp, rest-client

I have deployed a python machine learning code using fastapi but sometimes it is giving me the response and sometimes it doesn't. How to force it to wait for API response every time . Please help me I'm having hard time with this.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8000/predictbuy");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var param = new GannJson1{
         Diff_Step=V1_SStep,
         Last_Swing_Bars=V2_SSwing,
         H1= V3_SH1,
         L1=V4_SL1,
         O1=V5_SO1,
         C1=V6_SC1,
         V1=V7_SV1,
         HiLo1=V8_SHiLo1,
         H2=V9_SH2,
         L2=V10_SL2,
         O2=V11_SO2,
         C2=V12_SC2,
         V2=V13_SV2,
         HiLo2=V14_SHiLo2,
         H3=V15_SH3,
         L3=V16_SL3,
         O3=V17_SO3,
         C3=V18_SC3,
         V3=V19_SV3,
         HiLo3=V20_SHiLo3 
        };
request.AddJsonBody(param);
var response1 = client.Execute(request);
char pred1=(response1.Content)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fucntion :

```
public async void Function()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    var request = new RestRequest("http://www.google.com");
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var restResponse = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

   
    var result = restResponse.Content; 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier but showing this error                                                              ''The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'." . Buy I have async my python method.

Comment: @MukeshKumar are you sure, you had the async keyword in the signature of the method that's making the call (in this example the Main)